Can people’s worst curses be nullified by tapasya?
In the Mahabharata, Krishna cursed Ashwathama. But, Ashwatthama was a good person until his father’s death. Now adharma around Ashwatthama made himself also adharmic, and got him a curse. But can he, if he does tremendous sadhana, nullify his curse?

chanting the name of God can overcome all karma - "Sundered are the knots of the heart, torn off are all his doubts, and the seeds of his karma wear off, when the sight of the Transcendental One is gained" - Mundakopanishad II.ii.8

My goal is to shed all the bad karmas specifically as I really repent for my bad karmas. But not to destroy my good karmas but to increase them.

@Starship - thanks for submitting the edit. We need all the help we can get with cleaning up site standards.

Curses can be nullified. However for that, whatever karmic reasons due to which the curse was placed in the first place must be nullified. Sadhana can elevate a person's understanding, it can't rewrite your karmas. However through a better understanding of what is nashvara (temporary) the suffering due to any curse or anything else becomes less.
So coming back to Ashwatthama's case he must undergo the curse for its entire duration as prayaschitta for his actions. Forget Ashwatthama, in some legends, Vishnu himself is cursed by Bhrigu for killing his wife and that is given as an explanation for why Rama and Sita are separated in Ramayana. Even in the Mahabharata, Sri Krishna himself is cursed by Gandhari for conspiring to kill all her 100 sons and that is why the entire Yadu dynasty is destroyed.
But such fantastical examples are irrelevant for most regular people. In practice in Kali Yuga, first of all no one is really capable of cursing another person, and even if one does so, it is typically done out of ignorance and can be nullified by daivanugraha (divine intervention).
